# Languages Names Database

Tags: database

I'm wondering if there is any database out there with names of human languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the list is partial, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_name) is a pretty good list.

Comment: I'm already on it. but it's going to take me a lot of time to retrieve

Comment: You can write a simple parser:) It is `<ol> <li> <a title=` for every language:)

Comment: but i've used $("ol li a:first-child ") in jQuery instead :D